# Jenkins-CLI/Rest API to change the credentials in the created Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am creating a Jenkins Job using the Jenkins CLI/REST API, by copying Jenkins Job template, I am good with this.

Now I need to change the credentials in newly created Jenkins Job(like GIT Credentials, Artifactory, Docker), the created Jenkins Job have someones credentials, i need mine there)

Is there any API/provision to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Below jenkins Rest API is used to add the credentials to the user

curl --user username:password -XGET 'http://localhost:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' --data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "apicredentials",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "description": "apicredentials",
    "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
  }
}'

Once you add the credentials to the jenkins, change the cloned xml with the latest username and ID, and push the updated xml to create new jenkins job.